# Finding the Cartesian Equation of a Plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

Find the Cartesian equation of the plane containing points $A$ $(6,2,1)$ and $B$ $(3,-1,1)$ and perpendicular to the plane $x+2y-z-6=0$.

I get the vector $AB$ $=(-3,-3,0)$ and the vector of the plane  $x+2y-z-6=0$ which is $(1,2,-1)$. I know that the equation of the plane can be defined by the equation $A(x − x_0)$ $+$ $B(y − y_0)$ $+$ $C(z − z_0)$ $=$ $0$. How can I use this concept to find the equation of the plane?

Comment: OK, what did you try?

Comment: What's your intuition? Where'd you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two planes are perpendicular, the normal vector of the second plane (i.e. $(1,2,-1)$) is parallel to the first. To find the normal vector of the *first* plane, take the cross product: $(1,2,-1)×(-3,-3,0)=(-3,3,3)$. Finding the constant in the plane equation is now a matter of substitution: $k=-3\cdot6+3\cdot2+3\cdot1=-9$. So the plane's equation is $-3x+3y+3z=-9$ or $x-y-z=3$.

Comment: In my opinion it should be fine don’t give the complete solution immediately but give the minimum of elements such that who has asked the question can try to solve himself. Regards

Answer (score 1):

HINT

A good way to proceed is to find the normal vector to the plane $n(a,b,c)$ and then the equation by:

$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$

To find the normal $n(a,b,c)$ let’s consider that it has to be orthogonal both to AB and to the normal vector to the given plane m(1,2,-1).

To find the normal vector to two given vectors, cross product is a very effective way.

Comment: The normal vector $n(a,b,c)$ is $(3,-3,-3)$.

Comment: yes that’s good as its opposite or every other multiple, infact is more correct denote it as “a normal vector”

Answer (score 1):

You know that your new plane must be parallel to both $(-3,-3,0)$ and $(1,2,-1)$. Thus, you want a plane perpendicular to the vector perpendicular to these two vectors, let’s call it $\vec w$. You can find w by doing the cross product of the two vectors, then dotting it with $\vec x - A = (x-6,y-2,z-1)$ and setting equal to zero.